# Как узнать время работы компьютера за этот сеанс на Ruby

Tags: ruby

Есть ли какая то функция чтобы узнать время работы системы? или как мне получить эти данные?

Comment: Какое именно время работы системы имеется в виду?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> `uptime`
=> " 2:59  up 445 days,  3:49, 49 users, load averages: 1.00 1.56 1.66\n"
```